How to resolve cors error in Laravel Filament?
I have an issue, I am using filament.
so for example my site URL is something like this https://example.com/, I logged in to Filament and made some file changes it works!
in .env I have specified the APP_URL
but the issue comes when I load my site with https://www.example.com/, it again asks me to log in, and even after login, when I try to edit an image or any file, the existing or previous file doesn't come!
I check the console and it gives me an error of laravel cors.
